# Using WiFi to triangulate instead of GPS

Tags: mobile, geolocation, gps, components

I know its probably possible, but is it practical and doable to try and geo-position someone using WiFi to triangulate...

Thinking if I was underground and didn't have access to GPS, could I setup WiFi spots around the place to help locate someone.

Or if I was on a plane or a train (which is constantly moving), could I setup WiFi spots around the place to help locate someone.

Where would I start in doing this? Is there software components/infrastructure? If not would it be possible to do this... i.e. at a router level add location information to the packets about which router the incoming message was coming from and then the server being able to pick up on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly how the [Skyhook database](http://www.skyhookwireless.com/howitworks/coverage.php) (built into many phones) works. It uses cell towers and WiFi points to triangulate the position in the absence of a GPS signal.

Answer (score 1):

Google also does this with their street view vans—[they look for open wi-fi networks as they go](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2010/06/21/googles-street-view-trucks-reportedly-snooped-passwords-email/), and record their positions.

Answer (score 0):

This is already widely available. Google the terms `wifi` `location` `aware`.

This is how laptop "Lo Jack" theft recovery systems work, for example.

Comment: But doesn't this just locate you to an IP address, which is just a very rough locality and not very precise? Or is there an assumption of geo-coordinates associated with the hot spots?

Comment: @Brad Yes, as I understand it, the precision is dependent on hitting known hotspots. I'm sure it isn't great outside of, say, San Francisco or New York. Nothing like GPS, where available.